# Scikit-surprise maximum processing data limit

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

Can I use scikit-surprise in big projects like if I have 9-10 million ratings? I will be using the svd algorithm of surprise lib so I was thinking If this light weight library can handle this much of recommendation or I need spark?

Comment: Their web site shows examples with 100k and 1M ratings along with processing times.  It looks like the times are O(N), so multiply the sample times accordingly and see if that's too long for you.

Comment: Tim, I saw there website with svd algorithm and 100k data it takes 11 seconds and with 1 million it takes 2 minute 11 second so it became literally twice than expected time. I think It won't be wise to calculate that way. Is there any other way?